Terraform or azure tries using wrong storage account type
I'm creating a new storage account, storage container, storage blob, service plan, and finally - function. Everything but the last one is created successfully, and the last step fails with a message:
 creating Linux App Service (Subscription: "6bbf2436-dd82-400e-8476-a022f1f9eacc"
│ Resource Group Name: "mtr-resources"
│ Site Name: "mtr-hello-function11"): performing CreateOrUpdate: unexpected status 400 (400 Bad Request) with response: {"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"There was a conflict. The remote name could not be resolved:      
│ 'mtrstorageyqo20pyfgz.file.core.windows.net'","Target":null,"Details":[{"Message":"There was a conflict. The remote name could not be resolved:
│ 'mtrstorageyqo20pyfgz.file.core.windows.net'"},{"Code":"BadRequest"},{"ErrorEntity":{"ExtendedCode":"01020","MessageTemplate":"There was a conflict. {0}","Parameters":["The remote name could not be resolved:
│ 'mtrstorageyqo20pyfgz.file.core.windows.net'"],"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"There was a conflict. The remote name could not be resolved: 'mtrstorageyqo20pyfgz.file.core.windows.net'"}}],"Innererror":null}

If you look closely, you'll see this string: mtrstorageyqo20pyfgz.file.core.windows.net - which is obviously wrong, because it should contain the word "blob", not "file". Even more so, because I can inspect the created storage account in Azure, and see its type is Account Kind is BlobStorage. Here are the relevant terraform definitions:
resource "random_string" "random_storage_account_suffix" {
  length  = 10
  special = false
  upper   = false
  numeric = true
  lower   = true
}


resource "azurerm_storage_account" "mtr_storage" {
  name                     = "mtrstorage${random_string.random_storage_account_suffix.result}"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.mtr_rg.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.mtr_rg.location
  account_kind             = "BlobStorage"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"

  tags = {
    environment = "${var.environment_name}"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "mtr_hello_function_container" {
  name                  = "hello-function-releases"
  storage_account_name  = var.storage_account_name
  container_access_type = "private"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "mtr_hello_function_blob" {
  name                   = "MTR.ListBlobsFunction.publish.zip"
  storage_account_name   = var.storage_account_name
  storage_container_name = azurerm_storage_container.mtr_hello_function_container.name
  type                   = "Block"
  source                 = "./example_code/MTR.ListBlobsFunction/MTR.ListBlobsFunction.publish.zip"

  depends_on = [ null_resource.run_pre_hello_powershell_script ]
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "mtr_hello_function_svc_plan" {
  name                = "mtr-hello-function-svc-plan"
  location            = var.resource_group_location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "Y1"
  # sku_name            = "B1" # this doesn't work with zip package download for some reason - consumption tier needs to be used

  tags = {
    environment = "${var.environment_name}"
  }
}

data "azurerm_storage_account_blob_container_sas" "storage_account_blob_container_sas_for_hello" {
  connection_string = var.storage_account_primary_connection_string
  container_name    = azurerm_storage_container.mtr_hello_function_container.name

  start  = timeadd(timestamp(), "-10m")
  expiry = timeadd(timestamp(), "10m")

  permissions {
    read   = true
    add    = false
    create = false
    write  = false
    delete = false
    list   = true
  }
}

resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "mtr_hello_function" {
  name                       = "mtr-hello-function11"
  location                   = var.resource_group_location
  resource_group_name        = var.resource_group_name
  service_plan_id            = azurerm_service_plan.mtr_hello_function_svc_plan.id
  storage_account_name       = var.storage_account_name
  storage_account_access_key = var.storage_account_primary_access_key

  app_settings = {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME"    = "dotnet"
    "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE"    = "https://${var.storage_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/${azurerm_storage_container.mtr_hello_function_container.name}/${azurerm_storage_blob.mtr_hello_function_blob.name}${data.azurerm_storage_account_blob_container_sas.storage_account_blob_container_sas_for_hello.sas}"
    "AzureWebJobsStorage"         = var.storage_account_primary_connection_string
    "AzureWebJobsDisableHomepage" = "true"
  }

  site_config {
    application_stack {
      dotnet_version              = "8.0"
      use_dotnet_isolated_runtime = true
    }

    cors {
      allowed_origins = ["*"]
    }
  }

  tags = {
    environment = "${var.environment_name}"
  }
}

At this point I'm not even sure if that's a Terraform issue, or Azure issue, but I know that storage account address is wrong, because if I substitute the file word with blob, use the correct container and blob names + SAS key, I can download the file.
